# How to Checkmark the Table view cells in swift4 cell data is coming from server

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

As I tried in some scenarios but not perfectly working if I select the second cell the check mark from first cell is unchecking and sometimes the functionality is not working at all until I click 10 to 20 times .here is my code.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if tableView == switchTableView{
       return self.arrdata20.count
    } else
    {
        return self.arrdata.count
    }

    }


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if (tableView == self.switchTableView)
    {

        let cell:switchTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1") as! switchTableViewCell

        cell.nameLbl.text = (arrdata20[indexPath.row].name)
        print(cell.nameLbl.text)
        if (arrdata20[indexPath.row].emp_id == "001")
        {
            cell.isHidden=true
        }
        else{
            cell.isHidden=false
        }
        return cell



    }
    else  {
        let cell:PartyTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! PartyTableViewCell
        cell.venuLbl.text = "Venu: \(arrdata[indexPath.row].place)"
        cell.dateTimeLbl.text = "Date & Time: \(arrdata[indexPath.row].date)"
        cell.reasonLbl.text = "Reason: \(arrdata[indexPath.row].reason)"
        //        cell.timeLbl.text = ""
        return cell
    }

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    var rowHeight:CGFloat = 0.0
    if tableView == self.switchTableView{
    if(arrdata20[indexPath.row].emp_id == "001")
    {
        rowHeight = 0.0
    }
    else
    {
        rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension  
    }

    return rowHeight
    }else{
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


    id1 = "\(arrdata[indexPath.row].id)"
    print(id1)

        if self.switchTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
        {
           self.switchTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none

        }
        else{
            self.switchTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark



    }
}
```

After selecting the tableView cells I need to get the checkmark cells details like names in the cell as shown in image below[image]

Comment: cells a re-used, so you can't rely on the checkmark in the cell itself to track state.  You need to update your data model and then use that in `cellForRowAt:` to set the appropriate checkmark accessory

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare an array as:

```
var checked = [Bool]()
```

Then add this line of code in API call where you receive data in arraydata

```
self.checked = Array(repeating: false, count: self.arraydata.count)
```

In Table view delegate method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

    let cell:switchTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1") as! switchTableViewCell

    //configure you cell here.
    if checked[indexPath.row] == false{
        cell.accessoryType = .none


    } else if checked[indexPath.row] {
        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark


    }
    cell.title.text = self. arraydata[indexPath.row]["amp_id"].string
    return cell

}
```

add another delegate method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) {

        if cell.accessoryType == .checkmark {
            cell.accessoryType = .none
            checked[indexPath.row] = false


        } else  {
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
            checked[indexPath.row] = true


        }
    }

    on OKClickedButtonAction:

    serviceString = ""
    for i in 0..<checked.count{
        if checked[i] == true{
            serviceString = serviceString + self.arraydata[i]["emp_id"].string! + ", "
            print(serviceString)

        }
    }
    if serviceString == ""{
        self.servicesBtnLbl.text = "Tap to select"
    }else{
        self.servicesBtnLbl.text = serviceString

    }
```

It's working Solution, hope it will be helpful to you.

Comment: Your `didDeselect` function is still checking the current state of the cell accessory, rather than checking the selection array

Comment: @Paulw11 the checkmark functionality is working good but  I am getting error here at on click button function Type 'arraydata' has no subscript members in this line.               serviceString = serviceString + self.arraydata[i]["emp_id"].string! + ", "

Comment: and can you edit the code as after choosing the cells with check mark on click of ok button the choose cells has a names "name" I need to save that names in one string so that I have to pass that value into parameters to send post request

Comment: How is `arrayData` declared? You typically get that error when Swift can't infer the type of the array.  Are you using Foundation types like `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`?  Generally you shouldn't in Swift - Use the properly typed collections.  In fact, you shouldn't be using a dictionary at all - you should have an array of an appropriate struct so that you can access properties directly, by name,

Comment: can you tell me how can I do that using collections

Comment: in your code everything is returning false [false,false,false,false] if I select cells (checked) also

Answer (score 0):

You should update your

`tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` method
like

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! switchTableViewCell
        if cell.accessoryType == .checkmark {
            cell.accessoryType = .none
        } else {
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        }
}
```

But if you want the cell to keep its accessoryType even after reloading then you have to create an array to keep track of your accessoryType for each cell and update its value in the array when you update the accessoryType in UI in didSelectRowAt() and then in cellForRowAt() you have to use this array to set the accessoryType for each cell.